# What does <?> sign mean in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In an ArrayList for android such as the simplelistadapter I commonly see `ArrayList<?>` and in some tutorials I've reviewed the `<?>` is replaced by some value.  But I'm still not quite sure what variable or qualifier this stands for.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: It simply means that the ArrayList is of the type ? (ie: the type that the ArrayList describes or wraps is of type ?) which means that it can be any non-primitive type, as mentioned below. If you had an `ArrayList<?>`, it could contain a `Long`, a `String`, and even a `Map`. An `ArrayList<Integer>`, however, could only contain `Integer` values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938488/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-token-in-java/6938523#6938523

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does List<?> mean in java generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

For example, you can do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Integer(1));
list.add(new Integer(2));
.....

Integer i = (Integer)list.get(1);
```

Or you can do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(new Integer(1));
list.add(new Integer(2));
.....

Integer i = list.get(1);
```

As you can see, no need for casting.

Comment: Can an ArrayList store an array? ArrayList<Array> ?

Comment: Yeah, it can "store" any type, even ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> works.

Comment: I see, does that make the ArrayList 2D? And seeing that String, Integers are Objects. I assuming, ArrayList<Objects> works too right? :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that you can look at it as a 2D array kind of thing. You can go to 3D, 4D, etc.. if you want/need to. And yes, you can put *Object* there or any other type (not primitives).

Answer (score 2):

It means the `ArrayList` can contain any non-primitive type.

Answer (score 2):

The is a wildcard character for a generic type. Normally you declare an array list like:

```
ArrayList<String>
```

Where the type is specified exactly. The list will contain Strings. 
But sometimes you want to make a method or a class that takes an ArrayList of any type, or you want a field that points an ArrayList of any type

```
public void removeFirstItem(ArrayList<?> target) { 
...
}
```

Now this method can take an `ArrayList<String>`, or an `ArrayList<Long>`, etc, and do some operation on it.

Similiary you can have a local variable:

```
ArrayList<?> someList;
someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList = new ArrayList<Long>);
```

This works, whereas:

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Will not, since someList is specified as an `ArrayList<String>`, so only `ArrayList<String>` can be assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `ArrayList<? extends Object>`, which means it can contain any object inherits from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class (i.e. All objects in Java).

Comment: Hate to nitpick, but <em>all non-primitive objects in Java</em> would be more technically correct.

Comment: @TKKocheran but, what do you mean by "non-premitive" objects? Is there primitive objects in Java?

Comment: You can't make an `ArrayList<int>`, you can only make an `ArrayList<Integer>`, because an `int` is a primitive type and can't be null, but an `Integer` is a real Java type and can, in fact, be null.

Answer (score 0):

The  syntax is a "wildcard".  It's needed with Java generics:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html
- [What does List<?> mean in java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics)

A wildcard can be "bounded" or "unbounded".  The whole issue of compile/design time generic typing is closely associated with the runtime JVM issue of "type erasure":

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

'Hope that helps .. pSM

Answer (score 0):

This is a question regarding generics. The <(Kind of Object)> syntax represents that only a certain kind of object (class instance) may be passed as an argument. When you have the syntax, you are saying that any kind of class instance may be passed.

Comment: How about an Object class? The class contains 4 Strings in it. Can it still be used in an ArrayList?